# PostgreSQL query takes very longtime

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I have a table with 3 columns and composite primary key with all the 3 columns. All the individual columns have lot of duplicates and I have btree separately on all of them. The table has around 10 million records.
My query with just a condition with a hardcoded value for single column would always return more than a million records. It takes more than 40 secs whereas it takes very few seconds if I limit the query to 1 or 2 million rows without any condition.

Any help to optimize it as there is no bitmap index in Postgres? All 3 columns have lots of duplicates, would it help if I drop the btree index on them?

```sql
SELECT t1.filterid,
       t1.filterby,
       t1.filtertype 
FROM echo_sm.usernotificationfilters t1 
WHERE t1.filtertype = 9 
UNION 
SELECT t1.filterid, '-1' AS filterby, 9 AS filtertype 
FROM echo_sm.usernotificationfilters t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1
                   FROM echo_sm.usernotificationfilters t2
                   WHERE t2.filtertype = 9 AND t2.filterid = t1.filterid);
```

Filtertype column is integer and the rest 2 are varchar(50). All 3 columns have separate btree indexes on them.

Explain plan:

```
Unique  (cost=2168171.15..2201747.47 rows=3357632 width=154) (actual time=32250.340..36371.928 rows=3447159 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2168171.15..2176565.23 rows=3357632 width=154) (actual time=32250.337..35544.050 rows=4066447 loops=1)
        Sort Key: usernotificationfilters.filterid, usernotificationfilters.filterby, usernotificationfilters.filtertype
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 142696kB
        ->  Append  (cost=62854.08..1276308.41 rows=3357632 width=154) (actual time=150.155..16025.874 rows=4066447 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on usernotificationfilters  (cost=62854.08..172766.46 rows=3357631 width=25) (actual time=150.154..574.297 rows=3422522 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (filtertype = 9)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=39987
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_sm_usernotificationfilters_filtertype  (cost=0.00..62014.67 rows=3357631 width=0) (actual time=143.585..143.585 rows=3422522 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (filtertype = 9)
              ->  Gather  (cost=232131.85..1069965.63 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=3968.492..15133.812 rows=643925 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 2
                    ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=231131.85..1068965.53 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=4135.235..12945.029 rows=214642 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: ((usernotificationfilters_1.filterid)::text = (usernotificationfilters_1_1.filterid)::text)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on usernotificationfilters usernotificationfilters_1  (cost=0.00..106879.18 rows=3893718 width=14) (actual time=0.158..646.432 rows=3114974 loops=3)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=172766.46..172766.46 rows=3357631 width=14) (actual time=4133.991..4133.991 rows=3422522 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 131072  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 3512kB
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on usernotificationfilters usernotificationfilters_1_1  (cost=62854.08..172766.46 rows=3357631 width=14) (actual time=394.775..1891.931 rows=3422522 loops=3)
                                      Recheck Cond: (filtertype = 9)
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=39987
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_sm_usernotificationfilters_filtertype  (cost=0.00..62014.67 rows=3357631 width=0) (actual time=383.635..383.635 rows=3422522 loops=3)
                                            Index Cond: (filtertype = 9)
Planning time: 0.467 ms
Execution time: 36531.763 ms
```

Comment: "*as there is no bitmap index in Postgres*" - Postgres can use regular indexes as "bitmap indexes" using an ["bitmap index scan"](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgresql/operations)

Comment: `My query with just a condition with a hardcoded value for single column would always return more than a million records.`<<-- is there any combination of columns that could be a candidate key? Do you have a Primary Key?

Comment: @joop Yes, there is composite primary key -> combination of all the three columns in the table.

Comment: I suspect that there is no super efficient way to do what you want done with your current data model.  We might be able to make is 2 or 3 times faster, not  probably not 10 or 100 times faster.  You might need to change your data model.

Answer (score 1):

The second subquery in your UNION takes about 15 seconds all by itself, and that could possibly be optimized separately from the rest of the query.

The sort to implement the duplicate removal implied by UNION takes about 20 seconds all by itself.  It spills to disk.  You could increase "work_mem" until it either stops spilling to disk, or starts using a hash rather than a sort.  Of course you do need to have the RAM to backup your setting of "work_mem".

A third possibility would be not to treat these steps in isolation.  If you had an index which would allow the data to be read from the 2nd branch of the union already in order, than it might not have to re-sort the whole thing.  That would probably be an index on `(filterid, filterby, filtertype)`.

Comment: There is already an implicitly created index on those 3 columns as they form composite primary key. My worry is, the table has 9.5 million rows and a simple select * from table or select filterby from table takes around 15 to 20 secs. There are indexes already in place and I have done vacuum as well. How to optimize it as it would take longer if I add conditions or joins. What would be the reason behind this slowness?

Comment: @Manoharan.  What does the plan with "set enable_seqscan=off' look like?

Comment: It's the same with setting "set enable_seqscan=off'

Answer (score 1):

This is a separate independent way to approach it.

I think your

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1...
```

could be correctly changed to

```
WHERE t1.filtertype <> 9 NOT EXISTS AND (SELECT 1...
```

because the case where t1.filtertype=9 would filter itself out.  Is that correct?  If so, you could try writing it that way, as the planner is probably not smart enough to make that transformation on its own.  Once you have done that, than maybe a filtered index, something like the below, would come in useful.

```
create index on echo_sm.usernotificationfilters (filterid, filterby, filtertype)
   where filtertype <> 9
```

But, unless you get rid of or speed up that sort, there is only so much improvement you can get with other things.

Comment: This condition cannot be used as the subquery after NOT EXISTS should match both the conditions but the main query is not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only want to retrieve one record per `filterid`: a record with filtertype = `9` if available, or just another, with *dummy* values for the other columns. This can be done by ordering BY `(filtertype<>9), filtertype )` and picking only the first row via `row_number() = 1`:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT xx.filterid
        , case(xx.filtertype) when 9 then xx.filterby ELSE '-1' END AS filterby
        , 9 AS filtertype -- xx.filtertype
        -- , xx.rn
FROM (
        SELECT t1.filterid , t1.filterby , t1.filtertype
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.filterid ORDER BY (filtertype<>9), filtertype ) AS rn
        FROM userfilters t1
        ) xx
WHERE xx.rn = 1
-- ORDER BY xx.filterid, xx.rn
        ;
```

---

This query can be supported by a an index on the same expression:

---

```
CREATE INDEX ON userfilters ( filterid , (filtertype<>9), filtertype ) ;
```

---

But, on my machine the `UNION ALL` version is faster (using the same index):

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT t1.filterid
        , t1.filterby
        , t1.filtertype
FROM userfilters t1
WHERE t1.filtertype = 9
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT t1.filterid , '-1' AS filterby ,9 AS filtertype
FROM userfilters t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM userfilters t2
        WHERE t2.filtertype = 9 AND t2.filterid = t1.filterid
        )
        ;
```

---

Even simpler (and faster!) is to use `DISTINCT ON()` , supported by the same conditional index:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.filterid)
         t1.filterid
        , case(t1.filtertype) when 9 then t1.filterby ELSE '-1' END AS filterby
        , 9 AS filtertype -- t1.filtertype
FROM userfilters t1
ORDER BY t1.filterid , (t1.filtertype<>9), t1.filtertype
        ;
```